# Find outer element in HTML page after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, closest

I am trying to get the respective elements that enclose a number of buttons that may be clicked. As an example, I'd like to get the table row that contains the button that has been clicked.

In the code below, a click invokes the corresponding JavaScript, but "closest" returns an object that is not one of the table rows. I also tried `event.target` instead of this, and `parents` instead of `closest` but none did work.

```js
$(".ok").on("click", function(event) {
  console.log("ok clicked! " + JSON.stringify(event));
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  console.log("event  = " + event.target.nodeName);
  console.log("outer type = " + typeof(row));
  console.log("outer id = " + row.id);
  console.log("outer  = " + JSON.stringify(row));
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="outer" id="id-1">
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="ok">B1</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="outer" id="id-2">
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="ok">B2</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using closest you receive an array as returned value this can be seen if you simply log closest.
You have to access the first index to get the closest element you were looking for.

```js
$(".ok").on("click", function(event) {
  console.log("ok clicked! " + JSON.stringify(event));
  var row = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
  console.log("outer id = " + row.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="outer" id="id-1">
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="ok">B1</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="outer" id="id-2">
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="ok">B2</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **parent.parent** method of jquery to find row i.e. tr

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".ok").on( "click", function( event ) {
        var row = $(this).parent().parent();
        console.log("event  = "+event.target.nodeName);
        console.log("outer type = "+typeof(row));
        console.log("outer id = "+row.attr("id"));
        console.log("outer  = "+JSON.stringify(row));
      });   
 })
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr class="outer" id="id-1">
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="ok">B1</button>
        </td>
      </tr>       
      <tr class="outer" id="id-2">
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="ok">B2</button>
        </td>
      </tr>                 
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```